# Web API model binding

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, wcf-web-api

Given the ASP.NET Web API route:

```
example/{Id}
```

Which maps to the following ApiController action method:

```
public void Example(Model m)
{
    ...
}
```

With the model class defined as:

```
public class Model
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

When I post JSON `{ "Name": "Testing" }` to the URL `/example/123` then `Id` property of the `Model` object is not bound. It remains as 0 instead of 123.

How can I make the model binding also include values from the route data? I'd prefer not having to write custom model binders for what seems like a common use case. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 11):

The easiest way to accomplish what you're looking for is just to add another parameter to your method, and specify which parameter comes from which part of the request.

Example:

```
[HttpPost]
public void Example([FromUri]int id, [FromBody]Model m) {
    // ...
}
```

Now your route of `/examples/{id}` will successfully be able to bind - because the `Example` method has a parameter called `id` which it is looking for in the URI. To populate your model, you can either pass the ID in there as well, or do something like the following:

```
[HttpPost]
public void Example([FromUri]int id, [FromBody]Model m) {
    m.Id = id; // Make sure the model gets the ID as well.
}
```

Then simply post in `{ "Name": "Testing" }` to `/example/123` as you mentioned above.

Answer (score 5):

Our built-in ModelBinding infrastructure doesn't support partial binding of object from both URI and body. You can, however, implement a custom IActionValueBinder to accomplish this task. For example, please refer to the blog post http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jmstall/archive/2012/04/18/mvc-style-parameter-binding-for-webapi.aspx.

Answer (score 3):

The suggested process for this is normally to post to `/example` instead of `/example/{id}`. (though with Web API they normally use `/api/{controller}`)

Check out the table half way down this page: http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/routing-in-aspnet-web-api

Also check this link on "Inserting a record with ASP.NET Web API" - http://stephenwalther.com/archive/2012/03/05/introduction-to-the-asp-net-web-api.aspx

Comment: What if I'm PUTing a resource? In that case I don't want to remove the ID from the URL.

Comment: In that case you need to have it as a separate parameter on your action `(int id, Model, model)` Not the best solution I know.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the default binder can associate your Id route value to your Model Id property, so whatever d1k_is answer is as good as it gets I'm afraid; either that or writing your own binder (you might be able to write a more generic binder maybe? -if you have like a DomainEntity super class or something like that...)